# Adding a 404 page (component) in react

Tags: react-router

I'm new to React (familiar with Angular) and am using the scaffolded React project in VisualStudio2022.
I'm trying to add a 404 component, but whatever I try my 404 page always gets appended to the actual page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';
import { NotFound } from './components/NotFound';

import './custom.css'

export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
                <Route path='/fetch-data' component={FetchData} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make my `NotFound` component appear only when no other route matches?

Answer (score 0):

For 404 page you should specify the `path=*`

**React-router v6:**

```
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={<NotFound/>}
    />
```

[Source react-router v.6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#adding-a-no-match-route)

**React-router v5:**

```
  <Route path="*">
    <NotFound/>
  </Route>
```

[Source react-router v.5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match)

Also it seems that you use react-router v5 and it means you should wrap your routes with `<Switch>` component.

Comment: How do I know if I'm using v5 or v6? Which one should I be using?

Comment: Why do none of the examples I've worked from mention `Switch`? Is it a recent addition?

Comment: 1)You can check the version of react-router in package.json - `react-router-dom`. Which one to use? I'd use v6 since it's the most recent version with very convenient nested routing system. However, if you have to stick for some reason to class components and/or react version 16.8 or earlier it may be not the option for you. 
2) If you work with react-router v5, you use `Switch`, with v6 you use `Route` instead of `Switch`.  Since you use `component={}` and it works for you - you use react-router v5 and you have to use `Switch`.